# How to store and get internal app data from file in Android?

Tags: android

I am writing a simple Android Sudoku app, during the first stage, I want to store some Sudoku puzzle in a file and then get them. The file is a simple xml file, it's format just like:

```
<puzzle>23000...31</puzzle>
<puzzle>45013...67</puzzle>
```

There are 9 * 9 character in "puzzle" tag.

My question is, what's the correct directory for the file, and how to get the data from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your file in assets directory or even raw directory. Honestly, I would advise you to use the first solution: you will then be able to use inside your code:

```
getAssets().open(fileName)
```

- "assets" directory has to be at the root of your project (same level as ""src", "res", "libs"...
- "raw" directory has to be inside the "res" one.

Comment: Thank you, What is the raw directory? Does it mean the `/res/raw`?

Comment: Yes. And you can accces to it with "Resources.openRawResource()"

Comment: By the way, I'm mistaken: assets directory has to be at your project's root: same level as src and res directory... ;) I'll edit my post...